# My dream is to become a dentist or My future dream is to become a dentist

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was told that "future dream" is fine but for me the first one sounds fine because whenever we dream for something good to happen,it normally indicates "in the future".

For example: I want to become a Doctor. Here it is clearly indicating about the future then why "My future dream" is correct ? I don't know for sure whether it is correct or not.

Comment: *Your dream is **of a future** when you (hope to) become a dentist*. But you have that dream *now*, not in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit strange to talk about "a future dream":

How can you ever know what you will dream in the future? You can't.

Just stick to "dream".

You *can* add "future" to things that actually may/will take place in the future, so saying things like

> My dream is to become a dentist in the near future

is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. But for something with nefarious intent you would be better using vocabulary that reflects this. E.g. "I have grand schemes of turning my sadistic urges into a high paying profession"